# How do I extract the font name from a NSFontAttributeName?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscombobox

I have a NSComboBox and I want it to display the font name where the cursor is. I have the current code :

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.fontBox setStringValue:[self.doc.textStorage attribute:NSFontAttributeName atIndex:(self.doc.selectedRange.location - 1) effectiveRange:nil]];

}
```

Which sets the title of the combo box to the font but I get something similar to: `"ArialMT 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1001a95b0) fobj=0x1006511c0, spc=3.33"` And I just want to get Arial, or Times New Roman, or Helvetica, not that long string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSFont`'s `displayName` property.

```
NSFont *font = [self.doc.textStorage attribute:NSFontAttributeName atIndex:(self.doc.selectedRange.location - 1) effectiveRange:nil];
[self.fontBox setStringValue:font.displayName];
```

Comment: I would give you $500 if I could. I am such a n00b sometimes. All these methods and variables and everything is no confusing to me!